# Cannot access destination table [dbo]

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have connected to Azure Data Studio to access my SQL database on their platform. I'm using a Mac so I find this easier for now to access and manipulate data with SQL queries. I have been following the steps from the following from [sqlhack](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-data-import-using-azure-data-studio/).

When I get to step 4 I get the following error after pressing **import data**.

```
✗ Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpProcessException: Error inserting data into table. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access destination table '[dbo].[rest_review]'. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'rest_review', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CreateAndExecuteInitialQueryAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet& result)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpTextSynthesis.InsertIntoDB(String inputFilePath, String tableName, String schemaName, IReadOnlyList`1 columnInfo, SqlConnection connection, Int32 batchSize, SqlTransaction transaction, IList`1 allFinalTransformations, IList`1 allFinalTransformationColumns, IList`1 allFinalColNames)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpTextSynthesis.InsertIntoDB(String inputFilePath, String tableName, String schemaName, IReadOnlyList`1 columnInfo, SqlConnection connection, Int32 batchSize, SqlTransaction transaction, IList`1 allFinalTransformations, IList`1 allFinalTransformationColumns, IList`1 allFinalColNames)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.BcpProcess.CreateTableAndInsertDataIntoDb(String connectionString, Int32 batchSize, String azureAccessToken)
```

Thus I cannot import any data and so I ask, how can I properly import data to prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: *"The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'rest_review', database 'master', schema 'dbo'"* Why are you creating user objects in `master` in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu I have a database named `scrapyTB` and `master`, by following the instructions on the link above I right-click on `scrapyTB` and `import wizard`. Then the error above appears after following the steps up to step 4.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the comment as it has led me towards figuring it out. Turns out I had to import wizard from the `Azure` header and not the `Servers` on the database. Then this creates a table in the `Servers`. As I said this is new to me so I'm happy to have figured it out with your suggestion.